# Python .ipynb too large to open. Both Thonny, Jupyter Notebook shut down when trying

Tags: windows-10, python3

I am using Python 3.73  in Jupyter Notebook 4.4.0

The only
This page isn't responding:
Wait

Ultimately, Jupyter shuts down

[image]

I understand the issue is that Firefox is using too much memory. The file I am using is

somehow 173 MB. Not any fancy application/simulation. What happens is I ran a few programs

( e.g., find all primes between 2 and 10000) with incorrect indentation and Python iterated

the output too many times in an infinite loop that I did not at the time know how to end.

So I have, who knows, the output with each prime repeated maybe 1000x each. Similar issues with

other poorly written algorithms.  I then carelessly.

I've tried resaving as a JSON , opening and trimming but it's not working.

Any Ideas?

TIA.

saved the output band ended up with the 173 MB file

In case it matters, checking my Windows 10 Event Viewer, I notice events 1003, 1014 and 10016 around the time of the crash/closing of the two IDEs

Comment: have you tried running Jupyter Notebook server with larger memory allocation? `jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.max_buffer_size=75368709120 &`

Comment: Thank youi, found a solution. I will post it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming Windows-based:
I somehow accidentally ran into :
https://texteditor.co/

It accesses your problem file through File Explorer and opens it in a browser . You may then copy an paste it into a file editor like Notepad ++ and edit away.